# simple rest api get call not working android

Tags: android, rest

The below code is not working.

```
String url = "http://my/url/username/pswd";
String result = "";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv;
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);  
    request.addHeader("apikey", "DeveloperWy7ayxR");
    request.addHeader("Content-Type","application/json");

    ResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();  
    try {  
        result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);  
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();  
    Log.i("myLog", result); 

    tv.setText(result);
}
```

I tested url and headers with advanced rest client, it worked. Am I missed anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do networking operations in background.For e.g. run your code in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

For more info see
[android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

and also ADD network permission in android manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Now i'm trying with asynktask. If it also don't work I'll update my Question

Comment: @SGG Ok,lets try and reply.

Comment: Thanks, I saw example with asynctask. But i dont know why they are using. Now I got it.

Comment: @SGG Happy to help,enjoy.